# Collecting transaction fees and store it in pot

Tags: substrate

Want to collect a higher transaction fee (5%) during the use of transfer and store it in a pot account? How can I do that? Will I have to modify the transfer function of balance pallet.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L257

Also, how can I collect the extra transaction fees, need some help to write the code.

Comment: All information needed to understand the question should be included inside the question, not behind a link. Tag your question with the programming language used, and add the part of the code that is relevant as a code-formatted block. Secondly, there should be just one question, not multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fees are taken by `pallett-transaction-payment` and the [`ChargeTransactionPayment`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_transaction_payment/struct.ChargeTransactionPayment.html), which is a [`SingedExtension`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html) that collects the transaction payments.

If you want to collect `x%` per transfer, you can create a new signed-extension for `pallet-balances` that intercepts the `Call::transfer` and charges some extra money.

Note that this might clash with `ChargeTransactionPayment` if you include both in your runtime.

#### Code example

> This won't compile as-is; just showing you the direction.

```rust
pub struct TakeFivePercent<T>(PhantomData<T>);
impl<T: Config> SignedExtension for TakeFivePercent<T>  {
    const IDENTIFIER: &'static str = "TakeFivePercent";
    type AccountId = T::AccountId;
    type Call = T::Call;
    type AdditionalSigned = ();
    
    fn additional_signed(&self) -> sp_std::result::Result<(), TransactionValidityError> { Ok(()) }

    fn validate(
        &self,
        who: &Self::AccountId,
        call: &Self::Call,
        info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
        len: usize,
    ) -> TransactionValidity {
        match call { 
              Self::Call(Call::Transfer(dest, amount)) => {
                    // withdraw 5% of amount from dest
              }
        }
    }

    // note that we won't implement `pre_dispatch` and let it auto-impl
    // to valiadte.
    // https://crates.parity.io/src/sp_runtime/traits.rs.html#744-874
}
```

Lastly, note that you need to add this to the tuple of signed extension in the top level runtime file, where `construct_runtime!` lives.

```
pub type SignedExtensions = (
    Foo, 
    Bar, 
    ..,
    ..,
    TakeFivePercent<Runtime>    
)
```